# A Question about cardinal numbers and homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, ordinals

I'm studying my set theory lessons and I don't know if the following statement about homeomorphism between ordinal spaces is true or not and why.

"If $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal number then $[0,\kappa]$ is not homemorphic to $[0,\kappa+\kappa]$"

If anyone could help me I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $[0,\kappa+\kappa]$ has two disjoint compact sets of cardinality $\kappa$; does $[0,\kappa]$?

Comment: The first hint is wrong. I can think about two disjoint open sets of size $\kappa$: All the odd successor ordinals, and all the even successor ordinals.

Comment: (And writing my comment made me stop writing a hint which was essentially your second hint, rendered moot by your addition! :-))

Comment: Also, if $\kappa$ is singular, then its character is small. :-P

Comment: This is much better. :-)

Comment: @Ergonvi: You’re welcome!